# Search filter with nested list / children - jQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox tree structure that I am using to make selections - but I also want to be able to filter what is shown. If you type in the search box the items that don't match will be hidden. However this isn't working for the items in the nested lists. They are just ignored. I can't for the life of me figure out why they are not showing. I've tried multiple selectors and parent/child variations but nothing is working.

Here is my jsfiddle showing what I currently have:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p2avm56/2/)

Here is the bit of code that is handling the search filter:

```
    function searchFunction() {

      var input, filter, ul, li, div, i, heading;

      input = document.getElementById("input-search");

      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

      ul = document.getElementById("treeview");

      li = $('#treeview .list-group-wrapper li');

      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        div = li[i].getElementsByClassName("custom-control-label")[0];
        if (div.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As soon as a top category doesn't match the search, it gets hidden. Along with its children. Type for instance "ho" into the search field, and it "works", because that's in all levels.

Comment: Yes but what I want to happen is that the children don't get hidden. I want everything to show that is relevant to search. So if I type 'car' I will get cars on first and second levels and carrots on the third level.

Comment: I know. You were asking what you are doing wrong, and I told you. Now it's your job to fix it, for instance by hiding the <label>s instead of the <li>s. If you get stuck, put your edited code in the question.

Comment: I'm not seeing any aggression or rudeness in my previous comment. Anyway, your question does not read *at all* as if you already knew what the problem was (`I can't for the life of me figure out why they are not showing.`), or you would've asked how to prevent the children from getting hidden along with the parents from the start. So naturally I interpreted your comment as pretending to already know what I just told you, and repeating my "the problem is X" statement back at me. So excuse me for not being extremely friendly in my reply to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a different and simpler approach to this...

```
  function searchFunction(elm, list) {
    var input = $("#input-search");

    $(input).keyup(function() {
      var searchTerms = $(this).val();

      $('li').each(function() {

        var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 ||
          $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.toLowerCase()) > 0;
            $(this).toggle(hasMatch);

      });
    });
  }
```